# Rails 3.2.11 performance testing issue: Don't know how to build task 'test:benchmark'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, testing, rake

I'm following this [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/411-performance-testing) on performance testing, but I'm immediately running into an issue.

My app is rails 3.2.11, so according to the railscast it should include performance testing, but I don't have a folder called 'test' at all.  When I run 'rails generate performance_test homepage' nothing happens or is generated.  So I created one manually (to exactly match the railscast source code), but when I run rake test:benchmark I get the error

```
 Don't know how to build task 'test:benchmark'
```

If I add the 'rails-perftest' gem to my gemfile and run bundle, then again try to generate a performance_test nothing happens, and when I then run rake test:benchmark, it throws a different error of

```
uninitialized constant Rails::SubTestTask
```

I've been sure to include the following dependencies in my gem file:

```
 gem 'ruby-prof', group: :test
 gem 'test-unit', group: :test
```

Could anyone help advise me what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks!

Comment: I have an exactly same issue. Did u solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% certain on this, but I am guessing that you might not have your application.rb file configured accordingly. Also check your `Gemfile.lock` file and run the command `bundle install` because it could also be something funky going on with your Gems and dependencies.